# HTMLPanel doesn't disappear after setVisible(false) in GWT

Tags: gwt, visibility

I have the `HTMLPanel` that contains some elements

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="panel">
   <div>One</div>
   <div>Two</div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Also I have a CheckBox that sets panel's visibility.

```
 @UiHandler("myCheckBox")
    void doClick(ClickEvent event) {
       panel.setVisible(!myCheckBox.getValue());
    }
```

But when I set `panel.setVisible(false)` the inner divs is still visible. In firebug my panel is

```
<div aria-hidden="false">
   <div>One</div>
   <div>Two</div>
</div>
```

and user agent stylesheet has

```
div{
   display:block;
}
```

Why my inner elements still visible and why HTMLPanel doesn't desapear. Explain me, please. And if my solution is not the best, give me, please, better advice.

Comment: Can you inspect the runtime `display` property of the 2 child `div` elements?

Comment: the 2 child divs also have user agent stylesheet div{display:block;}

Answer (score 0):

If you will write HTML directly in **ui.xml** inside the `<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="panel"> </g:HTMLPanel>` GWT will not nest it, as it only nests GWT widgets.

So remove your div from ui.xml and in your IMPL class use this:

```
HTML html = new HTML("<div>One</div> <div>Two</div>");
panel.add(html);
```